# What does 「ような 」mean in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between

> 以下の条件を満たす**ような**日本語スピーカーを探しています

and

> 以下の条件を満たす日本語スピーカーを探しています

?

Comment: Please describe what is meant by weird?

Comment: I say weird because I could not find any reference as to what the ような in the first sentence means.  I could not say that the first sentence is incorrect either because the sentence was from a person who has passed JLPT1 (compared to me, well, you could say I am just a beginner).

Comment: Take an opportunity to search the term on this site, as I have found many questions addressing the same term.

Comment: @Jack, I already did...and I cannot find anything that would explain the use of ような in the sentence 以下の条件を満たすような日本語スピーカーを探していま.  I was hoping some native speaker could explain what it means as used in that sentence.

Comment: The sentence 以下の条件を満たす日本語スピーカーを探していますwhen translated, becomes "Looking for a Nihongo speaker who satisfies the following conditions". With the definition I find in this site and other sites', the ような in the sentence 以下の条件を満たすような日本語スピーカーを探していますis meaningless.  "Hen na hinongo" it seems to me.

Comment: @JACK Please stop attempting to answer questions in the comment section.

Comment: What I can say for sure is that you probably wanted to use 日本語話者.

Comment: I'm not confident enough to provide an actual answer, but I think it somehow makes it less direct or more polite. ような means 'such a (something) that (particular outcome)'. I would say that that 以下の条件を満たす日本語スピーカーを探しています means something like "we are looking for such Japanese speakers who (could/would) meet the following conditions".

Answer (score 1):

「よう」 can be used in many different patterns and can be combined with nouns, adjectives verbs and so on (check out [this excellent answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/70435/32952) about it). Essentially, it just means "like" or "similar to".

For example:

> ハリーポッターの小説【しょうせつ】。The  novel Harry Potter.
>
> ハリーポッターのような小説【しょうせつ】。Novel(s)  like Harry Potter.

The group of books that could fit the second sentence is wider than the amount of books that fit the first one. The books that fit the first sentence would be *strictly* the books in the Harry Potter series, but the books that fit the second description would include any fantasy novel that is *like* a Harry Potter novel or that *shares some qualities with* Harry Potter.

So, I think that adding 「ような」in your original sentence makes a difference:

> ①以下の条件を満たす日本語スピーカーを探しています。Looking for a Japanese speaker that satisfies the following conditions.
>
> ②以下の条件を満たす**ような**日本語スピーカーを探しています。Looking for a Japanese speaker that satisfies the following conditions, **or such**.

For example, if it was an IT job offer and the conditions to meet were "to hold a degree in Computer Science", someone who has a degree in Telecommunications Systems (a major related to Computer Science but different) would have more chances to get the job in the case ② than in the case ①, because in ① they are looking for Computer Science graduates specifically, but in ② they are looking for someone who can perform like a Computer Science graduate, regardless of whether he holds that particular degree or not.

[Here's another answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57527/32952) that explains it nicely.